# 1.5V to 30V fixed frquency PWM generator

Tags: pwm

I've need a circuit to take analogue power from a model train track (0-20V DC) as it enters an engine, then apply PWM at a reasonably fixed frequency (say 200Hz), and use this to drive the motor, so that the motor runs slower than it would strait off the track, but there isn't PWM through the tracks which seems to create dirty rails and stalled engines.

By arranging 2 NPN bipolars with a pair of diodes in reverse across each one, I can create a switch to amplify the PWM signal while retaining input direction. But I need a PWM drive circuit.

The awkward bit is, it needs to start at less than 1.5V, and handle up to 30V (should only ever reach 12V max under normal operation)

Comment: have you tried with a simple series resistor?

Comment: Use an external power supply (eg. +12V wall plug adapter) for the PWM and a MOSFET with a flyback diode. The amount of current the motor requires matters.

Comment: Try [DCC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Command_Control).

Comment: DCC would require the whole railway to be adapted (I have considered it), not just 1 problematic engine, a fixed resistor seems to reduce start-up current to motor, causing even more erratic behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I had suggested a 555 timer circuit, but Marcus Müller reminded me it needs to start at below 1.5V.
 A transistor-based astable multivibrator should be able to work at such a low voltage (possibly down to 1V). Here is one:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftr8Qb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

A standard basic design is not recommended, because one edge would be changing slowly instead of suddenly. This would waste energy as heat in your output transistors and could burn them.
 The improved design includes an additional diode and a resistor on each side (D and Rc2 in the schematic).
 C3 is definitely needed because the circuit might not start oscillating without it. Its value could be as low as 0.1µF or 100nF. If it's in parallel with the DC motor, it would have to be ***at least*** 100µF.
 Q3 is needed to buffer the signal and cause less loading on the circuit. If you could show me the schematic of what exactly you intend to do, I could tell you better values of the resistors and whether to add another buffer transistor.
 The T1 (time period of one cycle) is about:
T1 = 0.7(R1+Px)C1  --> Px in this case depends on the slider position.
 If it is in the middle, then it's about 23kΩ, so we get:
T1 = 0.7(1500+23000)100E-9 = 1.7ms
The total time period is T1+T2, and with the slider in the middle it is 2 times the single time period, in this case 3.4ms. The frequency is the reciprocal of the total time period, in this case about 300Hz.
T=T1+T2
f=1/T

Most importantly, you can adjust the duty cycle of your output, the ratio is probably around 17:1 (6-94% adjustment range, if I'm correct).
Please note that I might be slightly wrong in some of the recommended resistor values, but those can be easily changed.

UPDATE: Since you require a fixed 60% duty cycle, you don't need the potentiometer. Now you can use a wider range of resistor values.
I would start with the Rc and Rc2 resistors; change all of them to 3k3 (the 1k value at 20V would dissipate around 0.4W).
The R1 and R2 would need to be 33k and 51k to give you around 40-60 duty cycle ratios.
 Since the frequency is mostly dependent on the R1C1 and R2C2 values, I would suggest placing some sort of a voltage regulation either for the whole oscillator or just for the base resistors R1 and R2.  You could simply place 2 diodes like 4148 or 4001 in series to get around 1V to 1.2V and a dropping resistor from the power source to this circuit. You would have a much more constant voltage that way.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCPaD9.png)</sup>

Rdrop would have to be at least 1/2W resistor at 20V; at 30V it needs to be at least 1W.

Comment: a 555 won't start at less than 1.5V.

Comment: Ah, yes, I missed that part. Thank you. I will provide a better solution.

Comment: +1 because toy have D1 and D2 correctly oriented, many get it wrong.

Comment: When I built an astable multivibrator about a year ago, the frequency varied with input voltage - I never understood how to avoid this. 
I forgot to mention I want fixed 60% duty cycle as it's going to be embedded in a train, I assume this is simply a matter of fitting fixed resistors rather than the variable resistor.

Comment: I have updated my answer with more helpful suggestions.